# How can I prevent the raising of Correlative events?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two text box and i want to calculate each text box when the other changed.but my program fall into a loop.

```
    private bool suspendEvents = false; 

    private void txtYourPercent_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (suspendEvents)
            return;

        suspendEvents = true;
        txtMyPercent.value = 100 - txtYourPercent.value;
        suspendEvents = false;
    }

    private void txtMyPercent_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (suspendEvents)
            return;

        suspendEvents = true;
        txtYourPercent.value = 100 - txtMyPercent.value;
        suspendEvents = false;
    }
```

It's my way.This method is disgusting.Any better solution? ("WinForms")


If there is not another solution tell me to delete this question and use my (beep) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign both textboxes the same chenge event handler:

```
this.txtMyPercent.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtPercent_TextChanged);
this.txtYourPercent.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtPercent_TextChanged);
```

and then:

```
private void txtPercent_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == txtMyPercent)
    {
        txtYourPercent.Text = (100 - int.Parse(txtMyPercent.Text)).ToString();
    }
    else if (sender == txtYourPercent)
    {
        txtMyPercent.Text = (100 - int.Parse(txtYourPercent.Text)).ToString();
    }
}
```